# Autocorrelation of power spectrum

Tags: java, math, fft, spectrum, spectral

Have anyone idea how can I implement autocorrelation of power spectrum of one image? I tried using:

```
 autocorrel = ifft( | fft(power spectrum) | ^ 2 );
```

but its not working? Do you have any idea why or some other way?

Comment: suggest moving to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the correct formula.  Probably then, if you want an answer, more about "not working" would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocorrelation in *time domain* is done via convolution. Function is convoluted with self mirrored around 0. Thus, `autocorrel = linear_2d_convolution( S(x,y), S(-x,-y) )`, where `S` denotes power spectrum.

Comment: Convolution is fairly simple to implement (here's the [reference](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.auckland.ac.nz%2Fcompsci373s1c%2FPatricesLectures%2FConvolution_1up.pdf&ei=f2mYUJqdA4XRtAb8wIHgBA&usg=AFQjCNHze-VX1j6f-yJvnemgI9-pxB3oHQ&sig2=YAScEPdsK2bJ3BH69z0_Ig)). Notify if you have problems with it.